# Use different colors in scatterplot for Iris dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, kaggle

I am learning data-analysis in Python and using the matplotlib and seaborn library and I made a Notebook in Kaggle. I tried to make a scatterplot that shows the ratio between the width and length of sepal leafs and petal leafs.

```
sns.FacetGrid(iris, hue="Species", size=10) 

total_rows = iris.count
number_of_iris = len(iris)

sepalLengths = iris["SepalLengthCm"]
sepalWidths = iris["SepalWidthCm"]

petalLengths = iris["PetalLengthCm"]
petalWidths = iris["PetalWidthCm"]

plt.scatter(range(number_of_iris),(sepalLengths/sepalWidths))
plt.xlabel("ID")
plt.ylabel("Ratio")
plt.show()
```

Output is [image]

This code works correct but I am trying to display the plot in three different colors to distinguish the 3 different species. I changed the code into this :

```
total_rows = iris.count
number_of_iris = len(iris)

sepalLengths = iris["SepalLengthCm"]
sepalWidths = iris["SepalWidthCm"]

petalLengths = iris["PetalLengthCm"]
petalWidths = iris["PetalWidthCm"]

sns.FacetGrid(iris, hue="Species", size=10) \
   .map(range(number_of_iris),(sepalLengths/sepalWidths)) \
   .add_legend()
```

but received the error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-97e6cd0ab095> in <module>()
     10 petalWidths = iris["PetalWidthCm"]
     11 
---> 12 sns.FacetGrid(iris, hue="Species", size=10)    .map(range(number_of_iris),(sepalLengths/sepalWidths))    .add_legend()
```

How do I plot each specie into a different color?

A small part of the data is :

```
47,5.1,3.8, 1.34, 1.6,0.2, 8.0, Iris-setosa 
48,4.6,3.2, 1.44, 1.4,0.2, 7.0, Iris-setosa 
49,5.3,3.7, 1.43, 1.5,0.2, 7.5, Iris-setosa 
50,5.0,3.3, 1.52, 1.4,0.2, 7.0, Iris-setosa 
51,7.0,3.2, 2.19, 4.7,1.4, 3.36, Iris-versicolor 
52,6.4,3.2, 2.0, 4.5,1.5, 3.0, Iris-versicolor 
53,6.9,3.1, 2.23, 4.9,1.5, 3.27, Iris-versicolor 
54,5.5,2.3, 2.39, 4.0,1.3, 3.08, Iris-versicolor
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood how `Facetgrid.map` works. It expects a *function*  as first argument. Apart from that it is not clear what you are trying to achieve here, how do you imagine the final plot to look like? What should be on the x axis and y axis? Are you sure you don't want a [`lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html#seaborn.lmplot)?

Comment: I want a plot like this [link](http://imgur.com/a/oHxey) but for each specie a different color. In this case ID 1 to 50 has to have a color, 51 to 100 another color and 101 to 150 a third color.

Comment: http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seaborn provides an interface to data that is organized in DataFrames. If you want to use seaborn it would make sense to keep your data in a DataFrame, possibly adding the column you want to plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
iris["ID"] = iris.index
iris["ratio"] = iris["sepal_length"]/iris["sepal_width"]

sns.lmplot(x="ID", y="ratio", data=iris, hue="species", fit_reg=False, legend=False)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The same can be achieved with a usual matplotlib scatter plot like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

ratio = iris["sepal_length"]/iris["sepal_width"]

for name, group in iris.groupby("species"):
    plt.scatter(group.index, ratio[group.index], label=name)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use scatter method of pyplot module to draw scatterplot with the help of sklearn.preprocessing module.

```py
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Machine learning projects\iris.csv')
df.head()
```

Now we will use labelencoder from preprocessing module to change categorical variable into coded format(0-1-2 likewise).

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
encoding=LabelEncoder()
species_encoded=encoding.fit(df['Species']).transform(df['Species'])
species_encoded
```

Now we will use plt.scatter() method to draw scatter plot and pass arguments which are necessary.

```py
plt.scatter(df['SepalLengthCm'],df['SepalWidthCm'],alpha=0.4,s=100*df['PetalLengthCm'],cmap='viridis',c=species_encoded)
```

As shown in this image:

[image]